# Javascript get specific data from data table with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datatables

I have a datatable like this
[image]

What I want is to get the latest notes with the corresponding shipment_id (the topmost notes) when clicking the copy summary report button above and paste it to some text editors for email template. But what I get is

```
Hi, 

Below are the updates on the reimbursement requests for 3 shipment/s: 
//first row
FBA15MQMW8BB: 23-Feb-21 06:08,PM Super Updated
 23-Feb-21 06:06 PM :New Notes (updated) ----> not included
 23-Feb-21 06:06 PM Invoice and BOL ----> not included
//2nd row
FBA15TX03JTX: 23-Feb-21 07:01 PM,Latest
 23-Feb-21 07:01 PM New Notesss ----> not included
//3rd row
FBA15M1SQ8VH: 23-Feb-21 07:01 PM, Invoice and BOL

Will be sending updates again once I have additional information.

Thank you.
```

what i tried is

```
        Swal.fire({
            title: '<h2>Email Template copied to clipboard!</h2>',
            icon: 'info',
            html: '<p>You can now paste them anywhere completely.</p>',
            confirmButtonText: 'Send Updates',
            showCancelButton: true,
            showCloseButton: true,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            preConfirm: (confirm) => {
                var str='';
                var emailBody='';
                var count_shipments = $(".data-row").length;
                var SearchFieldsTable = $("#tbl-inbound-shipments-in-progress tbody");
                var trows = SearchFieldsTable.children(".data-row");

                $.each(trows, function (index, row) {
                    var shipment_id=$(row).attr("data-shipment-id");
                    var notes = $(row).attr("data-notes");

                    //this is the code for copying the notes
                    str += shipment_id + ": " + (notes ? notes : "No notes") + "\n\n";
                });

                //the email body/template to be pasted
                emailBody = 'Hi, \n\nBelow are the updates on the reimbursement requests for '+ count_shipments +' shipment/s: \n\n' + str + 
                    'Will be sending updates again once I have additional information.\n\nThank you.'
                
                var el = document.createElement('textarea');
                el.value = emailBody;
                el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
                el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
                document.body.appendChild(el);
                el.select();
                document.execCommand('copy');
                document.body.removeChild(el);
            },
```

EDIT: table structure and data fetch included as requested

```
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover display compact" id="tbl-inbound-shipments-in-progress" style="width:100%">
                                        <thead class="text-primary">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>#</th>
                                                <th>{{ __('Client') }}</th>
                                                <th>{{ __('SHIPMENT ID') }}</th>
                                                <th>{{ __('Case ID') }}</th>
                                                {{-- <th>{{ __('P/A/R') }}</th> --}}
                                                <th>{{ __('Updated Date') }}</th>
                                                <th>{{ __('Maturity') }}</th>
                                                <th>{{ __('Action') }}</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                    </table>
```

table data

```
 function load_inbound_shipment_in_progress() {
        window.ISIP = $('#tbl-inbound-shipments-in-progress').DataTable({
            //processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
                toastr.options.progressBar = true;
                // toastr.info('Requested Inbound Shipment data is now loaded.');
                $('#loading').hide();
            },
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            iDisplayLength: 10,
            ajax: "{{ route('admin.clients.inbound-shipment-in-progress', ['client'=>$client->id]) }}",
            createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
                var red = ((data.maturity > 5) && (data.pending > 0)) ? 'bg-danger' : '',
                    notes = (data.notes!='') ? data.notes : '',
                    shipment_id = (data.shipment_id_nolink !='') ? data.shipment_id_nolink : '';
                $(row).attr('data-row_id', data.id).attr('data-notes', notes).attr('data-shipment-id', shipment_id).attr('data-case_id', data.case_id).attr('data-pending', data.pending).attr('data-shipment_id', data.shipment_id).addClass(red);
                $(row).addClass('data-row');
            },
            dom: 'lBfrtip<"actions">',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    className: 'btn btn-custom-summary',
                    text: 'Copy Summary Report',
                    action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                        copyEmail();
                    }
                }
            ],
            columns: [
                { data: 'notes', name: 'notes', "class": "text-nowrap text-center", render: function(data) { return ''; }, fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        if (oData.notes != '') $(nTd).addClass('details-control');
                    }, orderable: false
                },
                { data: 'client', name: 'client', "class": "text-nowrap text-center" },
                { data: 'shipment_id', name: 'shipment_id', "class": "text-nowrap text-center" },
                { data: 'case_id', name: 'case_id', "class": "text-nowrap text-center", render: function(data, type, full) {
                    console.log(this)
                    var link = '<a href="https://sellercentral.amazon.com/cu/case-dashboard/view-case?ref=sc_cd_lobby_vc_v3&ie=UTF&caseID=' + (data ) + '&View+or+Respond=Submit" target="_blank" class="underlined">'+(data )+'</a>';
                    return '<span class="link-mode-'+full.id+'">' + link + '</span><input style="display: none;" id="edit-mode" class="edit-mode-'+full.id+'" type="text" value="'+ data +'">' + '    <button onclick="popup_save_case_id(this)" id="edit-case-id" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"> <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit<input type="hidden" class="case_id" value="'+data+'"> </button>';
                }},
                // { data: 'p_a_r', name: 'p_a_r', "class": "text-nowrap text-center" },
                { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at', "class": "text-nowrap text-center" },
                { data: 'maturity', name: 'maturity', "class": "text-nowrap text-center" },
                { data: 'action', name: 'action', "class": "text-nowrap text-center bg-light", orderable: false, searchable: false }
            ]
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you show table structure ?

Comment: okay sir @Swati i updated my question

Comment: table structure i mean how your notes columns data look alike ? are all datas display in some tags or in separate tags ?

Comment: the notes column is a `text` type from the database sir @Swati